# Deploy a cert to service fabric cluster without using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

I want to deploy a client certificate to my already created cluster that my service will use for outgoing requests to a dependent service and have that certificate already added to a KeyVault resource I provisioned. How can I get that cert deployed to my VM scaleset - is there some way I can authorize my service to access that Keyvault instance after which it will automatically deploy to my VMs, or is there some other process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a certificate to be in the certificate store, you can (re)deploy the VM scale-set with [certificate references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq#certificates) to the Key Vault.

```
"secrets": [
    {
        "sourceVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/myrg1/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/mykeyvault1"
        },
        "vaultCertificates": [
            {
                "certificateUrl": "https://mykeyvault1.vault.azure.net/secrets/{secretname}/{secret-version}",
                "certificateStore": "certificateStoreName"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Make sure the key vault is configured to [allow deployments to access secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter).

You can also access the Key Vault from code, by using [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/overview) or your own [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started). I'd prefer to use a client certificate (deployed to VM) to authenticate instead.

- If you choose MSI, each VM gets its own (managed) Service Principal, all of them need to be configured to be allowed [access to Key Vault data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-access-control). You need to do this yourself.
- If you choose to use Service Principal with ClientId & ClientSecret, make sure to keep Service Principal Client Secret in [protected configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-secret-management#encrypt-application-secrets). (this also requires a certificate) Make sure to configure an Access Policy for this SPN too.